# How to get model name out of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search controller something like this:

```
def index
  @foos = Foo.search
  @bars = Bar.search
  @search = [@foos, @bars]
end
```

And in my search index:

```
<% @search.each do |s| %>
  <% s.each do |s| %>
    <% s.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I write an if statement to find arrays only from the Foo model?

```
<% if s.modelname == "Foo" %> ?
```

Setting `<%= s.each do %>` shows that the array does have it's model name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
<% @search.each do |s| %>
    <% if s[0].class.to_s == "Foo" %>
      <% s.each do |s| %>
      <% s.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: With that we are checking the condition before entering into the sub loop ,So It will reduces the loop iterations.

Answer (score 5):

Try This :

```
<% if s.class.to_s == "Foo" %>
```

Comment: Why the `to_s` stuff when you can say `s.class == Foo` or better `s.is_a? Foo` instead?